# Computer Architecture pipeline stalls

Tags: mips, pipeline, cpu-architecture

First of all, sorry for my poor English. The question is a problem in the textbook for my Computer Architecture course. I've found the answer on the net but still cannot find out the details.

The following is the phase of instructions in a five-stage (fetch, decode, execute, memory, write) single-pipeline microarchitecture **without forwarding** mechanism. **All operations are one cycle except LW and SW are 1 + 2, and Branch is 1 + 1.**

```
Loop:             C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  C10 C11 C12 C13 C14 ...
LW   R3, 0(R0)    F   D   E   M   -   -   W
LW   R1, 0(R3)        F   D   -   -   -   E   M   -   -   W
ADDI R1, R1, #1           F   -   -   -   D   -   -   -   E   M   W
SUB  R4, R3, R2                           F   -   -   -   D   E   M   W
SW   R1, 0(R3)                                            F   D   W   M   ...
BNZ  R4, Loop                                                 F   D   E   ...
...
```

I have several questions:

1. Why can the 2nd instruction start D in C2? As I have learned, D-stage include "register read", but the previous instruction doesn't write back to R3 until C7.
2. Similar to previous one, what are the reasons that cause the 3rd inst's D to start at C7, and E to start at C11?
3. Why must the 4th inst start at C7 instead of C4?

This problem originate from the book "Computer Architecture : A Quantitative Approach 5e", example 3.11.

Comment: Can you edit the question with a link to where you found this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Classic RISC pipeline wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline) is very good.  Check it out if you haven't.

> 1. Why the 2nd instruction can start D in C2?  D includes reg-read, but the previous instruction doesn't write back to R3 until C7.

I'm not sure, I haven't spent a lot of time on the classic-RISC pipeline.  Based on what we see for this and ADDI, it looks like register-read happens in the E stage.

That perfectly explains E stalling until the previous load's write-back.  If you're sure reg-read is supposed to happen in the D stage for the pipeline you're studying, then this solution doesn't match your pipeline; it's correct for a different pipeline that doesn't read registers until Execute.

> 3rd inst's D start at C7, and E start at C11?

The D stage of the pipeline is occupied by the previous instruction until C7, at which point it can decode.

R1 isn't ready until cycle 11, at which point [the data can be forwarded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline#Solution_A._Bypassing) from the memory stage of the previous instruction, so the ADDI's Execute can happen in parallel with Writeback in the previous instruction.  This is called a "bypass".

A bypass can let ALU operations run with 1 cycle latency, so you could use the output of an ADD in the next instruction without a stall.

> 3. Why 4th inst must start at C7 instead of C4?

Because the previous instruction is stalled in the fetch stage, and it's an in-order pipeline; no out-of-order execution.

Comment: Thanks, if register-read is done in `EXE` stage, then the instruction phase can be totally explained!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your pipeline freezes the entire systems when it does a memory related operation (LW), other than than I cannot think of a valid reason why ADDI cannot perform its Decode in C4. I am not saying its valid for a load operation to freeze the whole execution, but that seem to be the "only" logical explanation.

Instruction 2 can perform its decode in C3, but it has to wait until instruction 1 has write back its data to `R1`. Thats why the execution of the second instruction is delayed until `C7`.

BTW when you said you've found the answer on the "net" is it from a credible source?

Comment: I think the OP is wrong about reg-read happening in the D stage.  ADDI is delayed for the same reason you identified for instruction 2 being delayed: input not ready, not any weird "freeze the whole machine" stuff.

Comment: @PeterCordes If that is the case why 'SUB  R4, R3, R2                           F   -   -   -   D   E   M   W'

Comment: @PeterCordes if that is the case why the decode of SUB instruction is delayed?

Comment: In-order execution: the instruction ahead of it is stalled.  See point 3 in my answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks. Looks like everything is down to the fact that decode stage trying to read registers. To me this doesn't make much sense as the job of the decode unit it tell "where" to read not "what" to read.

Comment: My conclusion (which I put in my answer) is that the diagram in the question only makes sense if reg-read happens in the E stage, not the D stage.  If reg-read had to happen in D, ADDI's D stage would have to wait until C11.  As far as what "makes sense", though, it would be possible to put "decode-and-read-operands" in one stage.  Reading operands from the register file has to happen somewhere.  If you (the CPU designer) don't give it its own stage, it has to be part of D or E, meaning that neither of them have names that fully describe them in that level of details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127279/discussion-between-isu-and-peter-cordes).

Answer (score 1):

**Why the 2nd instruction can start D in C2? D includes reg-read, but the previous instruction doesn't write back to R3 until C7.**

Ans - this is because DECODER stage in MIPS simple pipleline has two parts/sub stages.

DEC = DECODE + RR( REGISTER READ )

instruction can be decoded that is, the opcode can be read and decoded but, due to dependency in this case, RR will stall till first load instruction executes(fetches R3 from memory) and with simple forwarding in C7 next load can go to execution.

the breaking of DECODE stage in two substage is done to avoid structural hazard.
if you read diagram the "Computer Architecture : A Quantitative Approach" again, you will see a dotted line and solid line that is intentionally drawn to show overall work is decided in 2 parts(DECODE OPCODE + REG READ).

The other two question i agree with  @Peter Cordes

hope this helps.
Jaymin